# Appending Removing Dynamic elements in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem , Actually i want to append two two dynamic text boxes to a div tag in a button click, when next time the button clicked it should remove previously appended dynamic text boxes and to re append new text boxes!!

This is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1437/

```
   var addDiv = $('#divAdd');
    $(addDiv).parents('p').remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            $('<p><input type="text" style="width:120px;" id="p_new" name="p_new_' + i + '"/></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
```

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1441/) fiddle..
Also, never assign two same ID's to any tag, that's not the good way, you can assign same class to any number of tags, but ID's must be unique in html.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a dummy class on p tags that are appended and remove on apply selector on that class like this:

```
$('input[type=button]').click( function() {
 alert("test");   

    var addDiv = $('#divAdd');
 $('p.test').remove();
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                $('<p class="test"><input type="text" style="width:120px;" id="p_new" name="p_new_' + i + '"/></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
            }

});
```

[**Wokring Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ND9dP/)

Comment: classes will play most important role i think!! I have to work on that!!

Comment: yes apply a specific class on the dynamic generated p tag and remve by using the class selector, simplest solution for it

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all `input` inside `#divAdd` whose `id` is not `txtMobile`:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var addDiv = $('#divAdd');
    addDiv.find('input').not('#txtMobile').remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        $('<p><input type="text" style="width:120px;" class="p_new" name="p_new_' + i + '"/></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
    }
});
```

Also, you need to use `class="p_new"` instead of `id="p_new"` since `id` must be unique.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/1442/)**